# How to display separate swimlanes for each story, but only in a certain status in Jira?

Tags: storyboard, jira, jql

In a software development Jira board, I'm looking for a way to

1. have all stories which are in status "in progress" in a swimlane showing the associated sub-tasks in statuses.
2. see the swimlane disappear when the story's status changes to a status which is not "in progress". The project is not yet in a state where it doesn't happen that a story needs to be aborted and go back to "open" again in which case I don't want to see the story as a separate swimlane, but as one item in the boards "everything else" swimlane.

I cannot use

- Swimlanes based on stories because once they've been displayed as swimlane they always are. I need a swimlane to go back as a single cartd into the "everything else" swimlane as soon as all sub-tasks are resolved.
- JQL queries because I don't find a way to separate stories into different swimlanes (I want one per story) because I don't know how to self-reference the story by its identity in the query and split the result set.

I need to use Jira classical because I don't want to invest time in understand new-type projects which mostly seem to remove features and hide them for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding a Kanban-Board-Filter which hides `issuetype = Sub-task AND status = [the status you want to trigger hiding the swimlane on, e.g. Closed]` which would result in

```
!(issuetype = Sub-task AND status = Closed)
```

appended to the already configured condition.